# foreign key error occuring when tried to create normal way

Tags: mysql

I have a `room_tb` table and seller table. I want create a `fk`.

```
ALTER TABLE seller
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_romid
FOREIGN KEY (roomID)
REFERENCES room_tb(roomID)
```

`roomID` is primary key in my `room_tb` table and is `autoincrement`.
`roomID` is simple integer with same characters as `roomID` in `room_tb` but is not `autoincrement`.

I am getting error:

> 1452 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`iwant2`.<result 2 when explaining filename '#sql-13ec_2c7'>, CONSTRAINT `fk_romid` FOREIGN KEY (`roomID`) REFERENCES `room_tb` (`roomID`))

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check database for any datas..sometimes the available datas also create a problem.so better delete those datas.